# PublicKey/Pem file Authentication for SSH in Pantheon Files

Tags: pantheon-files, ssh

Is it possible to connect to ssh server using pantheon-files with public key or .pem file, i really need this integration.
The GUI now only show server, surname and password field i cant see a way to select a ssh key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should submit an "wishlist" issue on Github about this ( at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues). This is not something that is currently implemented within Files.

Answer (score 2):

You could try like this:

1. Set your **config** file in ~/.ssh
2. Define your host as follows:

   ```
   Host some.mydomain.com        
     HostName mydomain.com
     Port 22
     User myuser
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_id_rsa
   ```
3. Next, in Pantheon Files just set your SSH host as **some.mydomain.com** with no username and password.
4. Connect and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

It actually works if you use the default id file (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`). You need to enter the server name like `user@host` and leave user name and password fields blank. Then, there comes a pop-up asking you to enter the id file password and all works.